# Guava Transform Map<String, List<Double>> to List<TargetObject>

Tags: java, guava

I have to transform/convert source object into target object. Please see the sample code below using Guava.

Below is a test class where i have a Source object as `Map<String, List<Double>>` which i need to transform it to `Target`.

```
public class TestMapper {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String key = "123AA";
        List<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>();
        values.add(15.0);
        values.add(3.0);
        values.add(1.0);

        //source
        Map<String, List<Double>> source = new HashMap<String, List<Double>>();
        source.put(key, values);

        //target
        List<TargetObject> target = new ArrayList<>();

        //transformation logic      
    }
}
```

Target Object:

```
public class TargetObject 
{
    private int pivotId;
    private int amt1;
    private int amt2;
    private int amt3;

    public int getPivotId() {
        return pivotId;
    }

    public void setPivotId(int pivotId) {
        this.pivotId = pivotId;
    }

    public int getAmt1() {
        return amt1;
    }

    public void setAmt1(int amt1) {
        this.amt1 = amt1;
    }

    public int getAmt2() {
        return amt2;
    }

    public void setAmt2(int amt2) {
        this.amt2 = amt2;
    }

    public int getAmt3() {
        return amt3;
    }

    public void setAmt3(int amt3) {
        this.amt3 = amt3;
    }
}
```

Can you please suggest if i can do with Guava or any other good API?

I think i can do it in below manner...Let me know if ther is better way to do it...

```
Map<Integer, TargetObject> transformEntries = 
                Maps.transformEntries(source, new EntryTransformer<Integer, List<Integer>, TargetObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public TargetObject transformEntry(Integer key, List<Integer> values) {
                            return new TargetObject(key, values.get(0), values.get(1), values.get(2));
                        }
                });
```

Comment: You can do that with a for loop, once you have decided how a String and a list of doubles is transformed into 4 ints.

Comment: I can do it with for loop. But i am looking if i can do it using Guava in a better way.

Comment: Then show us how you do it with a for loop, because we don't know how a String and a list of doubles is transformed into 4 ints.

Comment: The above produces a `Map`, not a `List`. Other than that it should work so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Guava [Lists](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html):

```
List<TargetObject> resultList = Lists.transform(source.entrySet(),
    new Function<Entry<Integer, List<Integer>>, TargetObject>(){...});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Guava [FluentIterable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) for this transformation, since it produces an immutable list that is easier on more safe to work with:

```
        List<TargetObject> resultList = FluentIterable.from(source.entrySet()).transform(
            new Function<Map.Entry<String, List<Double>>, TargetObject>() {
                @Override
                public TargetObject apply(Map.Entry<String, List<Double>> integerListEntry) {
                    ...
                }

            }).toList();
```